# How To convert an Object Of A Class in xml in c#

Tags: c#

I have tried this code but I'm not getting it. Please explain this code:

```
public static XmlDocument ConvertToXml(object list)
{
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlSerializer _XmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(list.GetType());

    using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        _XmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, list);
        xmlStream.Position = 0;
        xmldoc.Load(xmlStream);
        return xmldoc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @mayurgnu at StackOverflow any debugging help requires minimal code + expected result. Can you expand your question to specify what is the expected result and what you are getting instead? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like working , id I try the same with an object it give me xml for object as well as if I pass a list it gives ArrayOf the type. can you elaborate what you are looking for?

Comment: Adding to raghav710's comment, you can read [ask] about how to write a question that at least meets the minimal requirements on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work.

You can use Generic function like this.

```
public static XmlDocument ObjectToXmlDocument<T>(T obj)
{
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, obj);

        stream.Position = 0;
        xmldoc.Load(stream);
    }

    return xmldoc;
}
```